# Finding points on one arc based off of another

Tags: geometry

I have two arcs and I am trying to be able to correlate one to the other I know all of the points on my arc to the right and need to find a way to find the points on my arc to the left. I do know the starting point of the arc to the left but that is all.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It is not at all clear what you are trying to do. How can you hope to find points on an arc when all you know is one of its endpoints?

Comment: Also a picture might be useful for understanding

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.